# UTC Timestamp since 1900

Tags: digital-forensics

While reverse engineering a system I found a time stamp with a peculiar year:

```
UTC:'20.09.118 17:41:38'
```

It seems as if this is the UTC timestamp since 1900, which would result in

```
UTC:'20.09.2018 17:41:38'
```

This seems the most plausible explanation. But I am not 100% sure, it could just as well be the timestamp since 1901 or 1902, ...

Does anybody recognize this software pattern of saving a UTC timestamp since 1900?

Comment: Probably, for compatibility with MSOffice and OpenOffice, the "zero date" is 1899-12-30